# Column 'ListId' does not belong to underlying table ''

Tags: 2010, feature

I am trying to run the following code I found somewhere here, but I got this exception on this line
DataView dv = new DataView(dtResults);

```
using (SPWeb web = properties.GetWeb())
            {

                SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

                // Query all Web sites in this site collection.
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";  // How to do it for the current site only?

                //Ask for all lists created from the Calendar template.
                query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"106\" />";

                DataTable dtResults = web.GetSiteData(query);
                //String[] Webcolumns = { "WebId" };
                //DataTable dtDistinctWebResults = new DataView(dtResults).ToTable(true, Webcolumns);
                DataTable dtDistinctWebResults = new DataView(dtResults).ToTable();

                String[] Listcolumns = { "ListId" };
                DataView dv = new DataView(dtResults);
                //dv.Sort = "WebId";

                DataTable dtDistinctListResults = new DataView(dtResults).ToTable(true, Listcolumns);

                foreach (DataRow oRow in dtDistinctWebResults.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow oListRow in dtDistinctListResults.Rows)
                    {
                        if (oListRow["WebId"].ToString().Equals(oRow["WebId"].ToString()))
                        {
                            SPList oList = web.Lists[new Guid(oListRow["ListId"].ToString())];
                            var field = oList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkspaceLink];
                            //field.Hidden = enable;
                            //field.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly have never taken the approach you are with the data but the first thing I would try is explicitly identify the fields you need in the [SPQuery.ViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx) property. I want to say that by default (if none are specified) its supposed to pull everything but it seems maybe something is missing in your case.

**Updates Based on Comments**

To Loop through the lists, check against the base template, and update the lists perform something similar to the following:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < web.Lists.Count; i++)
        {
            if (web.Lists[i].BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Events)
            {                    
                //Update List
            }
        }
```

Comment: How else would you do this? I only need to HIDE the Create workspace option in the Calendars list when the Activate feature button is click on site setting -> Manage features.  The problem is that there might be more than ONE list of type Calendar in the site.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Also, how many lists are on a single site? If its not a really big number I don't see why you can't just loop through the lists, check the base type, and update the field accordingly.

Comment: 2010 as the tag

Comment: Not many lists, its small sites, but I dont know how to that? Can you paste some code ?

Comment: Updated my answer with some code.